# Android app crashes with Resources$NotFoundException after display resolution has changed

Tags: android, mobile-application, android-app-bundle, xiaomi, miui

From the analytics and crash tools that are used the following situation has been discovered: a user installs the app from Google Play and use it without issues on his Xiaomi Mi 11 Ultra device; the reported Screen Resolution is 1440x3007, Screen DPI 560. Then a crash with Resources$NotFoundException was reported when the app is started but the Screen Resolution is 1080x2255, Screen DPI 420.

The app bundle supports generating configuration APKs for screen density resources so when app is installed resources for the current DPI are selected.
Is changed DPI the reason for this crash (missing resources for the new DPI) and if yes what can I do to prevent the crash?

I don't have the device to test but saw in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ww0DMppe4RA) that the display resolution can be changed.

I know about [MissingSplitsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/missingsplits/MissingSplitsManager) but it is deprecated.

> This interface is deprecated. the feature is now obsolete. Installs
> with missing splits are now blocked on devices which have Play Protect
> active or run on Android 10.